# Tapestry SelectModelFactory Multiple LabelProperties

Tags: tapestry

I have a select dropdown in a Tapestry form that is populated by objects through a SelectModelFactory. I am currently displaying the first name of the object to the client but I would like to display both the first name and the last name and I'm having a devil of a time figuring out how to add another labelProperty. My model is created per the below code:

```
List<Person> persons = personFinderService.findPersons();
personsModel = selectModelFactory.create(persons, "firstName");
```

I've tried several things:

```
(persons, "firstName" + "lastName")
(persons, "firstName" & "lastName")
(persons, "firstName" && "lastName")
(persons, "firstName + lastName")
(persons, "firstName & lastName")
(persons, "firstName && lastName")
(persons, "firstName", "lastName")
```

But I can't get both names to display. Any help would be much appreciated. Tapestry isn't much used so there isn't a lot of online support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either create a new method in your `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    ...
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

and then `personsModel = selectModelFactory.create(persons, "fullName");`.

Or work with internal `SelectModelImpl` and `OptionModelImpl` directly.

Comment: That's exactly what I wound up doing (create the method with both first and last name). Thanks for the answer! I tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet for it to register.